# Does headphone impedance make any difference except for volume?

Tags: headphones, electronics, impedance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the effect of impedance on headphone sound quality?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/650/what-is-the-effect-of-impedance-on-headphone-sound-quality)

Does headphone impedance make any difference except for volume?

Comment: you could try to make a blind test with matched volume. Some headphones come with different impedance versions. Just go to a local dealer and try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Headphones with high impedance often have a flatter signal. They often times have different types of drivers powering the speakers that are higher quality but need to receive more power.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, The affect on volume is often the most apparent but there will be an affect on the sound its self. Think of it like this, your amplifier does not knot that "headphones" are connected, it does however know that a load is connected. The behavior of your amp will change based on the load, this is often reflected by a drop or rise in volume but varying loads can affect, the frequency range a bit, response times, and the over sound characteristics that you end up hearing.